# Tree Shaking RxJS Angular 5

Tags: angular, rxjs

I created a brand new Angular project with the ng cli, and added nothing. I then ran

ng build --prod --aot -vc=true -sm -oh=none

and I used source-map-explorer to see what was tree-shook. I see a bunch of rxJs stuff that I am not using, like observable, merge map, etc. Is this normal? Is this because other node modules are using it, like angular? is it 14% of my vendor bundle.

```
Angular CLI: 1.5.0
Node: 6.11.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 5.2.2
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

@angular/cli: 1.5.0
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.0.42
@angular-devkit/core: 0.0.29
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.0.52
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.1.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.8.0
@schematics/angular: 0.1.17
typescript: 2.4.2
webpack: 3.8.1

"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your dependencies a lot of the `@angular` modules/components use rxjs and thus in each of those components tree shaking occurs on the operators that are imported to each respective angular module/component.

Especially the angular router which is all observables.

Comment: That is what I thought also, IIS is  compressing my site so the bundle does get a lot smaller in the real world. Thanks for responding. I will mark this as the answer tommorow. I just want to see what anyone else has to say. I appreciate you making the time to make me better.

Comment: Glad I could help